# VBA for MAC navigating browser with elaborate functions

Tags: macos, vba

I have a Google Analytics Macro that works perfectly fine in Windows, but I need to use it in MAC.
I am having trouble with opening a browser and navigating in it. This is an example of code that I use and didn't find support in MAC:

```
Set HTMLDoc = oIExplorer.document
HTMLDoc.all.Email.Value = GAlogin ‘this is a string I got in another part of the code
HTMLDoc.all.passwd.Value = GApassword ‘this is a string I got in another part of the code
For Each objButton In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If objButton.Type = "submit" Then
        objButton.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next objButton
```

I found ways to open and navigate browser, but none of them would support this kind of code. More specifically, none of them allowed the `getElementsByTagName` part nor going through the elements and clicking a button.
Does anyone know how I could navigate and use a browser in MAC that would support this functions?